# Python No such file or directory error uploading file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, joblib

```
src/
   model/
      Logistic Regression_model.pkl
   test/
      test.py
```

My code
`logistic_model = joblib.load('../model/Logistic Regression_model.pkl')`

I have a structure with a folder layout like this. When I run the test.py file, I get the error
`'FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: '../model/Logistic Regression_model.pkl'.`
When I run the same codes as .jpynb, it does not give any errors.

When I tried it as jupyter notebook it worked. When I try it as a python file, I get the same error.

Comment: I was running this directly in vs code. When I enter the test folder with the console and run the `python test.py` command, the paths work properly without errors. Running it directly through Vs Code gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path to file or remove ".." from src.

Comment: It works when I use the whole path, but I don't want to show the whole path in the project.

Comment: @MichealRosa try to locate file in the same directory as working py-file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is in the space between "Logistic" and "Regresion".

Instead of : "Logistic Regression_model.pkl"
try putting :"Logistic_Regression_model.pkl"